# Chrome browser stuck when executed Selenium tests in parallel

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run Selenium tests on Chrome in parallel with two threads(both threads running on same machine), sometimes I've seen one of the chrome instances stuck(i.e UI interactions do not happen) for some time or indefinitely.

This causes test execution to take more time or fail test unnecessarily.

Could you please help to understand if this is known behaviour when tests run on same machine? If not, what are the causes and solutions? Also guide on how we can pro-grammatically(using Java) set memory for Chrome browser which is running through Selenium?

Comment: are both browsers using the same chromedriver?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg, yes both using same chromedriver.exe but different chrome driver instance because as they are running in parallel each has its own ChromeDriver() instance.

Comment: If the two selenium test threads are independent from each other, i.e, do not need to communicate, try running them as seperate processes. Make a program which runs a batch file (selenium_tests.bat), which executes test1.exe and test2.exe, so maybe this way they get more resources from the machine since they are seperate programs, and not threads.

Comment: @TDHM, is each ChromeDriver() instance using a different port?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg, yes each one is using different port.